# what is the meaning of "Plato’s attic"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, metaphors

This is the context:

> She seemed to Hartley almost an ethereal presence and he could not imagine for a second that in Plato’s attic of perfect forms there could exist a prototype of phibba that was better than the copy he loved.

— *The Family Mansion: A Novel* by Anthony C. Winkler

Is attic means attics in the houses and it’s a metaphor for the philosophy of Plato or is it a term?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a well-known phrase.  I'm guessing it's a combination of two things:

1. "Plato's cave," referring to the philosophical [Allegory of the Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave), which proposes that all things in the world are shadows cast by "perfect forms" that exist in some abstract sense.
2. The attic of the house as being a place where you store all sorts of things that might be useful in the future.

So "Plato's attic of perfect forms" is a metaphorical storeroom where all the perfect forms are kept until a time when they might be needed.

By saying that "he could not imagine" a prototype better than the "copy he loved," the author is saying that Phibba (note that this is a proper name and should be capitalized) is such a amazing woman that the [Platonic ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_idealism) of the essence of all womankind could not be an improvement over Phibba herself.